# MySQL server with website hosting with managed hosting

Tags: web-hosting, mysql, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I work for a small business, and I *am* the "IT Department". I also happen to be a summer intern, so after I leave the number of IT staff will be 0 for an indefinite period of time. I need a place where I can reliably put up the company's website as well as the mySQL+PHP backend. Good redundancy is a plus, as well as easy administration for my IT-challenged colleagues. Managed hosting would be good, so the PHP versions can update without my company having to hire an admin.

**EDIT**: The company already has a mySQL+PHP server running locally which hosts the existing website. My assignment is to find a remote server where the latest versions of mySQL+PHP will be maintained and where there is a very small chance of unintended downtime. Can you recommend anything?

Answer (score 0):

Managed hosting is quite expensive and any shared hosting which has phpmyadmin thrown it should be sufficient.

Of course you'll be leaving behind all relevant usernames and password and instructions on how to FTP files up and down and make any tweaks to the database using phpmyadmin that can't be done using the admin pages you've provided. And you'll be telling them where the local backups of the remote data go, and some pointers in case they need to restore the data. You are? Good.

Comment: Yeah. I'm sure that the server we have right now (local) is good enough to act as a backup. FTP-ing files should be the same as the local server except with different input in various fields (nothing that can't be explained concisely in a WORD document). They use PHPmyAdmin already, so no problem. Can you recommend anything like what you described?

Comment: There are any number of hosting companies and a number of sites listing hosting companies together with customer reviews. I hesitate to recommend even the company I use, because I have no idea about downtime. However seeing as you twisted my arm, I use asmallorange.